# Flutter - AnimateCamera not working with newLatLngBounds

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

I'm using Google map and after adding lot of marker i want to move camera to newLatLngBounds to show all the marker visible to user. But i'm facing this Error.

**Error** using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions., null)

```
Future<void> getCenterMap() async {
double minlatitude = loadInformationMap[0]['latlng'].latitude,
    maxlatitude = loadInformationMap[0]['latlng'].latitude,
    minlongitude = loadInformationMap[0]['latlng'].longitude,
    maxlongitude = loadInformationMap[0]['latlng'].longitude;
for (int i = 0; i < loadInformationMap.length; i++) {
  if (minlatitude >= loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].latitude) {
    minlatitude = loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].latitude;
  }
  if (minlongitude >= loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].longitude) {
    minlongitude = loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].longitude;
  }
  if (maxlatitude <= loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].latitude) {
    maxlatitude = loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].latitude;
  }
  if (maxlongitude <= loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].longitude) {
    maxlongitude = loadInformationMap[i]['latlng'].longitude;
  }
}
googleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
    LatLngBounds(
        southwest: LatLng(minlatitude, minlongitude),
        northeast: LatLng(maxlatitude, maxlongitude)),
    100));
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @tinocoam No brother, still i can't find a solution. if you find a answer please add here.

Comment: What I did to work was to encapsulate googleMapController.animateCamera inside a Future.delayed function, like this: Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
          LatLngBounds(
              southwest: LatLng(minLat - ajuste, minLong - ajuste),
              northeast: LatLng(maxLat + ajuste, maxLong + ajuste)),
          5));
    });

Comment: @tinocoam i hate magic numbers but this does solve it, and its not just a lifecycle thing if you use future.delayed with duration.zero it doesnt solve the error, so it does need this extra 100 milliseconds which could obviously change 

Comment: There is no real fix for this issue, only potential workarounds but I've tried every single one and am still able to reproduce the issue - ongoing for years now.  Any issue report on GitHub is unfortunately marked as resolved and locked despite not having actually having a fix.  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27936, https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/445

Answer (score 0):

*before animate camera await for some time:*

```
Future<void> _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
_mapController.complete(controller);
_googleMapController = await _mapController.future;
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => getCenterMap());
```

}